# Prove that $a^{2n+1}+(a-1)^{n+2}$ is divisible by $a^2-a+1$ for any $a \in\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $a^{2n+1}+(a-1)^{n+2}$ is divisible by $a^2-a+1$ for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I tried to use induction here, but it seems like a dead end. Maybe I should somehow use binomial theorem?

I need a hint

Comment: $a \vdots b  \Leftrightarrow$ a is divisible by b

Comment: Please make the body of your post a selfcontained text that make sense without knowing the title.

Comment: Let $\omega$ be the complex cubic root of $1$. Then $(-\omega)^2-(-\omega)+1=0$. Then you can verify if $(-\omega)^{2n+1}+(-\omega-1)^{n+2} = 0$.

Comment: $a$ is an integer

Comment: Hint: Use $a^2\equiv a-1 \pmod{a^2-a+1}$

Comment: $(a-1)^{n+2}=(a^2-a+1)(a-1)^n-a(a-1)^n$

Comment: @Sergey To avoid that the question is eventually closed/deleted , please add context in the form that you write out what you tried. "I tried xy" is not considered as enough context.

Comment: Hint: Prove that $x_n=a^{2n+1}+(a-1)^{n+2}$ satisfies an integer linear recurrence of order 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the divisibility, I am going to prove that  $a^{2 n+1}+(a-1)^{n+2}\equiv 0 \quad \pmod{a^2-a+1}$
\begin{aligned}
& a^{2 n+1}+(a-1)^{n+2} \\
\equiv & a^{2 n+1}+\left(a^{2}\right)^{n+2} \quad\left(\bmod a^{2}-a+1\right) \\
\equiv & a^{2 n}\left(a+a^{4}\right) \quad\left(\bmod a^{2}-a+1\right)\\
\equiv & a^{2 n}\left[a+(1-a)^{2}\right] \quad\left(\bmod a^{2}-a+1\right)\\
\equiv & a^{2 n}\left(a^{2}-a+1\right) \quad\left(\bmod a^{2}-a+1\right)\\
\equiv & 0 \quad\left(\bmod a^{2}-a+1\right)\\
\end{aligned}
$\therefore a^{2 n+1}+(a-1)^{n+2} \text { is divisible by } a^{2}-a+1.$